# How to add a line feed in multiline column displayed in list view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, custom-list, list-view-web-part, infopath-rules

I have a list with a column of type "multiple lines of text", which is updated by concatenating several other columns together when I save the item.

I want to control the formatting of the list view web-part by inserting line feeds or carriage returns between the columns as they are concatenated together so it is easier to read.

I am using an infopath form to create and edit the list items. I added a xml document to the site assets with substitution codes for cr=#xD;, lf=#xA; and crlf=#xD;#xA;. I then created a data connection to the xml file and use the substitution codes in an infopath rule that updates the destination column by inserting cr between each of the single columns. It is inserting the substitutions, but it doesn't show up right when i look at the list view webpart. I also tried using `<BR>` but that isn't working either.

any ideas?

Comment: The approach you describe works fine for me using the #xA from an xml secondary data source. The text is concatenated with a line feed and the field shows with line feeds in the list view.

Comment: ok, i can see it is working now that I changed the type of text to allow to 'plain text'.